# How to Test multiple columns of pandas for a condition at once and update them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a data frame like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10,20,30,40], 'col2':[5,10,15,20], 'col3':[6,12,18,24]})
test
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   10  5    6
1   20  10   12
2   30  15   18
3   40  20   24
```

I wanna replace the values which are greater than 10 in col2 or col3 with zero. I wanna use loc function for this purpose.
My desired output is:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   10  5    6
1   20  10   0
2   30  0    0
3   40  0    0
```

I have tried the following solution:

```
cols_to_update = ['col2', 'col3']
test.loc[test[cols_to_update]>10]=0
test
```

It shows the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([('c', 'o', 'l', '1'), ('c', 'o', 'l', '2')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

When I use a single column to test the condition, it doesn't show 'KeyError', but now it also replaces values in other two columns.

```
test.loc[test['col2']>10]=0
test
```

Output is:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   10  5    6
1   0   0    0
2   0   0    0
3   0   0    0
```

1. Can we use loc for this purpose?
2. Why is loc behaving like this?
3. What is the efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `numpy.where` to conditionally replace values of multiple columns:

```
import numpy as np

cols_to_update = ['col2', 'col3']
test[cols_to_update] = np.where(test[cols_to_update] > 10, 0, test[cols_to_update])
```

The expression `test[cols_to_update] > 10` gives you a boolean mask:

```
    col2   col3
0  False  False
1  False   True
2   True   True
3   True   True
```

Then, `np.where` picks the value `0` whenever this mask is `True` or it picks the corresponding original data `test[cols_to_update]` whenever the mask is `False`.

---

Your solution `test.loc[test[cols_to_update]>10]=0` doesn't work because loc in this case would require a boolean 1D series, while `test[cols_to_update]>10` is still a DataFrame with two columns. This is also the reason why you cannot use loc for this problem (at least not without looping over the columns): The indices where the values of columns 2 and 3 meet the condition `> 10` are different.

When would `loc` be appropriate in this case? For example if you wanted to set both columns 2 and 3 to zero when any of the two is greater than 10:

```
test.loc[(test[cols_to_update] > 10).any(axis=1), cols_to_update] = 0
test
# out:
   col1  col2  col3
0    10     5     6
1    20     0     0
2    30     0     0
3    40     0     0
```

In this case you index with a 1D Series (`(test[cols_to_update] > 10).any(axis=1)`), which is an appropriate use case for `loc`.

Comment: you explained very well. Can you please explain one more thing that why there is a KeyError in my solution? Thanks

Comment: @Naveed That's because you are indexing with a DataFrame, as explained in the answer. The Dataframe `test[cols_to_update]>10` is what you use as the key, however this "key" is not contained in the DataFrame index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10,20,30,40], 'col2':[5,10,15,20], 'col3':[6,12,18,24]})
test[['col2', 'col3']] = test[['col2', 'col3']].where(test[['col2', 'col3']] <= 10, 0)
```

output:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 40 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your kind response.  I am little bit confused that Can we use loc to test a condition for multiple columns or not?

Comment: You can for a single column, eg `test.loc[(test['col2'] > 10), 'col2'] = 0`, but you'll run into trouble with multiple columns because the condtions you set apply to the rows, so row `1` poses an issue, as in that row `col2` is not larger than 10, but `col3` is.