# Pythonic was of testing multiple columns in dataframe for condition and creating a new column based on results

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have an arbitrary number of columns to check the condition as to whether any of them is equal to 1, then I want to create a new column based on the results. I want to do something along the lines of [how-to-test-multiple-columns-of-pandas-for-a-condition-at-once-and-update-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049554/how-to-test-multiple-columns-of-pandas-for-a-condition-at-once-and-update-them):

```
cols=['col_1', ..., 'col_n']
test['col_n+1']=np.where(test[cols] > 0, 1, 0)
```

However, when I run this, I get an error of:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1
```

I understand why this is being thrown, but cannot find a pythonic way of doing this (I'm able to iterate through the dataframe and individually evaluate each column, etc., but the code is ugly)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `test[cols]` is 5 columns, how do you want to put that in 1 column?

Comment: in this case `n` = 5.

Comment: I see, you need one column. The answer below works out

Answer (score 1):

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10,20,30,40], 'col2':[5,10,15,20], 'col3':[6,12,18,24]})

col=['col2','col3']
```

#Check where any row has value greater than 19

```
test['test'] =test[col].gt(19).any(1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Ha! I was just testing using `any.` Thanks!